# Generate row_number() with partition using only self joins in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

We all use the ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By Column1 Order by Column2) when we are trying to order rows based on a partition column. Here is the question I have -

Given a table Employee with two columns (Emp_id, Salary). How do I return the top 10 rows(ordered by Salary) from this table without using any of the following.

rank, cte, sub queries, top, limit, generators, order by, variables, user defined or in built functions or built in database specific functionalities.

Here is the SQL Fiddle link
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/22ab9/10

The only way I got this to work to some degree is to use a self join and use 'having' to filter the top 10 ranks. However I am not able to generate row numbers. If there is a tie I assign the same rank to the participating row resulting in incorrect top 10 rows returned.

--Here is what I wrote

```
select e1.Emp_id, e1.Salary, count(distinct e2.salary) rnk
from
  Employee e1
  join
  Employee e2 on e1.Salary <= e2.Salary
group by
  e1.Emp_id, e1.salary
having count(distinct e2.salary)<= 10
```

--Here is how I am expecting it to behave

```
select *
from
(
select e1.Emp_Id, e1.Salary, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by Salary desc) rnk
from Employee e1
) a where rnk <= 10
```

How do I handle ties in the self join and still be able to assign a different rank/row_number to it?

Comment: why not just `select top 10 * order by Salary desc`?

Comment: Please read my conditions in the post "rank, cte, sub queries, top, limit, generators, variables, user defined or in built functions or built in database specific functionalities." These are not allowed.

Comment: Yeah, by WHY isn't top and ORDER BY allowed?

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Ideally top should be allowed but assume this is an interview question, how would you answer if someone would ask you this with the stipulated restrictions?

Comment: Gordon may have hooked you up, but to answer you question--if it was an interview question I'd say "I wouldn't, because that would be counter productive, slow down the query, and be hard to maintain". I can understand them perhaps wanting to restrict you, but they could be looking for you to call them out on their silliness. I.E. no sense in writing a program to do calculations when there are libraries already there.

Comment: Gordon did nudge me in the right direction. Yes, this silliness was communicated to the interviewer but they wanted to know if the candidate "really" knew SQL. I don't know if this is really a smart way to judge candidates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two comparisons.  Assuming `emp_id` is unique:

```
select e1.Emp_id, e1.Salary, count(distinct e2.salary) as rnk
from Employee e1 join
     Employee e2
     on e1.Salary < e2.Salary or
        (e1.Salary = e2.Salary and e1.emp_id <= e.emp_id)
group by e1.Emp_id, e1.salary
having count(distinct e2.salary) <= 10
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I modified your query slightly and got it to work.                                             select e1.Emp_id, e1.Salary, count(*) as rnk
from Employee e1 join
     Employee e2
     on e1.Salary < e2.Salary  or
        (e1.Salary = e2.Salary and e1.emp_id <= e2.emp_id)
group by e1.Emp_id, e1.salary
having count(*) <= 10

Comment: @peppa . . . The `count(distinct)` comes from your query.  It is the difference between `rank()` and `dense_rank()` so I thought it was intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Taking lead from Gordon's answer, I think this worked for me.

```
select e1.Emp_id, e1.Salary, count(*) as rnk
from Employee e1 join
     Employee e2
     on e1.Salary < e2.Salary  or
        (e1.Salary = e2.Salary and e1.emp_id <= e2.emp_id)
group by e1.Emp_id, e1.salary
having count(*) <= 10
```